# Drag and drop in grid view

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I want to drag a image view in the grid view which support in android version 2.2.

I can implement it using drag listener but for 3.0 and above, but i want to implement it in 2.2 also.

Please suggest me any example if any one have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that can be achieved in 2.2 but not using Standard Android API. You have to use some 3rd Party to achieve it. I have accomplished Drag and Drop in GridView Task by using [PagedDragDropGrid](http://www.androidviews.net/2012/12/pageddragdropgrid/). if you required only in single page then do it by creating only one page in ExamplePagedDragDropGridAdapter. Hope this will help you.

Comment: TNR, I have 1 que, can i have 2 pages on the same screen?

Comment: @Dhrupal ,No, I hope that is not possible. you just do some case study on the Widget and try it on your own. as far as I know it is not possible.